# VS2008 solution creates VS2010 .suo files at compile time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I have Visual studio 2008 application. I installed Visual studi0 2010. From then, all the VS2008 solution files create VS2010 .suo files at compile time. I am not able to open any VS2008 files. I uninstalled VS2010 ans still the issue remains.

Can anybody help to let me know how to fix this issue. I need to create VS2008 .suo files at compile time for the solution.

Thanks,

Comment: Delete the .suo files created with VS 2010 and try opening with VS2008

Comment: I tried to delete the .suo file and open the solution in VS2008. When I compile the VS2010 .suo file gets created again.